# How to create empty jar using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have to create few empty jars at a specific location which is going to work as stub jar. Is there anyway I can create multiple jar using maven. Say for the following structure.

```
<project.baseDirectory>/out/msg/first.jar
<project.baseDirectory>/out/msg/second.jar
<project.baseDirectory>/out/msg/third.jar
<project.baseDirectory>/out/msg/forth.jar
<project.baseDirectory>/out/msg/fifth.jar
```

Comment: What do you want to do with these jars? How do you want to use them?

Comment: My project is going to use these jar as stub jar in their legacy application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want completely empty jars (i.e. files), the correct way to do this would be to use the `ant` plugin for Maven.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <touch file="first.jar"/>
                    <touch file="second.jar"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The reason is Maven is not meant to create files like this on the fly (unless it's generating sources using a plugin like wsdl2java).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a dummy jar by not having any sources and deps in a dummy modules.
Ex:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummyJar</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dummyJar</name>
  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then use this artifact and the dependencies plugin to copy this jar to specific locations that are you need them to be at.

Also a suggestion, if possible would recommend that these empty jars be under target folder instead of the base project dir as these are not really sources. But it really depends if you can do it in your legacy build.